# How does the iPhone/iPad versions of Dropbox display Microsoft Word documents?

Tags: ios, ms-word, dropbox, ibooks, .doc

Is Dropbox just making use of iOS libraries (iBooks code?) to read .doc/.docx files and view them?

Or did Dropbox actually have to code some kind of wrapper to get .doc/.docx files to display properly?

The web version of Dropbox just downloads the file so seems like whatever the viewer is it must be iOS-specific,

thanks,
tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the QuickLookFramework:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009672

and the DocumentInteraction Topics:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1

Comment: thanks jaydee3, I'm building a web app, would you know of web-based frameworks like QuickLook?

Comment: just open the file in a new tab, or show it in an iframe? this should work i guess. the browser handles the preview, if it is able to. this is just a guess though.